# Is problem of finiteness in the sense of von Neumann field FG algebras solved for any class of groups?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-rings

there is an open problem: Does for every field $F$ of characteristic prime and every group $G$, the group ring $FG$ finite in the sens of von Neumann? Is this problem solved for any class of groups?

I ask because for example Kaplansky's Conjecture is solved for torsionfree noetherian groups and fields of characteristic 0.

Comment: I'm not sure of what I know about the ring theoretic structure of von Neumann *algebras*. I know they're *related* to von Neumann regular rings, but I gather they are not the same.  I know quite a bit about von Neumann regular rings, and that the group algebras that are VNR are completely characterized. Maybe you can help me out by filling me in on the gap between von Neumann algebras and rings?

Comment: @rschwieb I have to weak knowledge at that moment. Sorry for that.